# Proof: $f: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R^2 , x \mapsto (x,0)$ is $ \mathcal B^1 - \mathcal B^2$ measurable but not $\mathcal L^1 - \mathcal L^2$ measurable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I have to prove the above. I know that:

$f$ is $\mathcal B - \mathcal B^2$ measurable $\Leftrightarrow$ $f^{-1} (B) \in \mathcal B^1 \: \:\forall B \in \mathcal B^2$

(for $\mathcal L^1 - \mathcal L^2$ measurable just swap the $\mathcal B$ with $\mathcal L$).
I don't really see why this should be violated for $\mathcal L$.

Anny tipps or ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think the prove might involve some generator $\mathcal E$ of $\mathcal B^2$, since the condition for measurability holds still if you swap $\mathcal B^2$ with $\mathcal E$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess $\mathcal{L}$ means the Lebesgue sigma algebra so take $A\not\in \mathcal{L}^1$ then $A = f^{-1}((A,0))$ but $(A,0) \in \mathcal{L}^2$ because it's a nullset.

Comment: Ah, nice, thanks a lot, thats acutally very simple. Do you also have a tipp on how to show that it IS $\mathcal B^1 - \mathcal B^2 $ measurable?

Comment: Use that the borel sets are generated by intervals. If you have shown it for that generator you are done. So it's enough to show it for sets $[a_1,b_1) \times [a_2,b_2) \in \mathcal{B}^2$. Consider the two cases $0 \in  [a_2,b_2)$ and $0 \not \in  [a_2,b_2)$.